# Why doesn't the magnetism of a magnet decrease even after continuously attracting and repeling electromagnets in a motor running for years?

Tags: work, ferromagnetism

I asked an electrical engineer whether he has ever opened a motor that ran for years at least 8-9 hours a day? If yes, were the magnets still powerful enough to attract/repel other magnets or irons?

He answered that he opened motors that ran for 8-9 hours daily for 15 years and the magnet didn't lose their magnetism, he could still use those magnets in other motors.

I was wondering if the force of magnet(s) were used in doing useful work by didn't its force (attraction/repulsion) decrease after usage in such work?

Comment: Why do you think the magnetic properties should change?

Comment: This may help - [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

Comment: @JonCuster - The OP may be thinking about an engine that works until it runs out of gas, or holding his arms up until they get tired. If you are not familiar with how magnets work, it isn't clear why they should stay the same.

Comment: @mmesser314 - I agree that we do not know precisely what the OP is thinking, making it harder to craft an answer. As well, the type of motor impacts things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magnetic forces of magnets acting on wires in an electro-motor can decrease in time, if the magnets demagnetize (decrease the level of magnetization). This can happen naturally with time, as the magnetic material evolves towards stabler state of magnetic domains after the magnets are created, but is usually a very small/negligible effect. Demagnetizing can also happen due to overheating/mechanical shock/too high current in the winding, which should be avoided.

In theory, if there is no overheating/shocks/too high currents, the magnets may never completely demagnetize. They keep their magnetized state for a very long time. The fact these magnets participate in transformation of energy in electro-motor (from EM potential energy to mechanical energy) means there are forces putting stress on the magnetized state and acting to destroy it, but if the forces are not high enough, they won't be successful and the magnets won't lose their magnetism.

Magnet being magnetic is similar to a wheel having teeth (gear): if the forces between the teeth are not too high, the geared wheel does not loose the teeth. Similarly, if the forces demagnetizing the magnets are not too high, the magnet does not lose magnetism.